GitHub Action with Pandoc & GNU Parallel
I have the following GitHub Action to convert with pandoc to several output files, where condition_check_files runs on a push on main and returns the names of added & modified markdown files:
  conditional_pandoc:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-22.04'
    needs: [ condition_check_files ]
    if: needs.condition_check_files.outputs.bool_files_changed == 'True'
    env:
      list_changed_files: ${{ needs.condition_check_files.outputs.list_changed_files }}
    steps:
      - name: install_pandoc
        uses: pandoc/actions/setup@v1
        with:
          version: 3.5
      - name: run_pandoc
        run: >
          # List types which will only use --standalone. You can easily add more extensions if you're fine with this setting
          $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES = "latex pdf html docx odt"';' \
          parallel --jobs 0 \
            # Pandoc creates an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree); reuse this by saving/reading from .ast
            pandoc --from markdown {} --to native -o '{.}.ast' ';'\
            for i in $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES';' do \
              pandoc --from native '{.}.ast' --standalone -o '{.}.$i' ';' \
            done';' \
            # You can easily add individual conversion rules by using pandoc after the 'done' part. Keep in mind to finish all non-comment lines with backslash
            rm '{.}.ast' ::: $env:list_changed_files

but when I push a modified .md to the repo, I get the follwing error for this job:
pandoc: {}: withBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I really can't seem to find an explanation on how to solve this on the web, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit I
After @Benjamin W. advised to remove the comments, I did and got the following error:
Run $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES = "latex pdf html docx odt"';' \ parallel --jobs 0 \
/home/runner/work/_temp/57d44aa5-ea88-4a42-b677-caf9210aa3af.sh: line 1: =: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

Edit II
With the helpful comments and a bit of experimenting I got the following code:
      - name: run_pandoc
        env:
          Only_Standalone_Output_Types: "latex pdf html docx odt"
        run: |
          parallel --jobs 0 \
            pandoc --from markdown --to native {} -o '{.}.ast' ';' \
            for i in $Only_Standalone_Output_Types';' do \
              pandoc --from native '{.}.ast' --standalone -o '{.}.$i' ';' \
            done';' \
            rm '{.}.ast' ::: $list_changed_files

and now the Action finishes without an error! However, the output is nowhere to be found. Since I don't have any error, I don't know where to look for a solution.
For reference, this bash script works locally (you need to insert some example Markdown files to work on)
#!/bin/bash

test_files="test.md test/beispiel.md"
OUTPUT_TYPES="latex pdf html docx odt"

parallel --jobs 0 \
    pandoc --from markdown --to native {} -o '{.}.ast' ';' \
    for i in $OUTPUT_TYPES';' do \
        pandoc --from native '{.}.ast' --standalone -o '{.}.$i' ';' \
    done';' \
    rm '{.}.ast' ::: $test_files


You can't intersperse a multi-line command with comments, it breaks your parallel invocation.

Also, > for multi-line run commands is generally not a good idea, it turns your entire script into a single line.

Thanks for the hint with the comments, I moved those outside of the run command. I chose > because that fixed an error with | with the multiline for-loop. Is there a way to improve that? Also edited the question with the new version

Copy the parallel --jobs 0 ... into a script.sh and execute locally. Is the problem related to github actions at all? What is $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES = doing? It's not a valid shell syntax. There is no point in writing code that can't be executed - consider writing small parts of code and testing them, before you move to parallel. Does the code works in sequence? Do you really need parallel? Why are all ';' quoted?

@KamilCuk script.sh already exist, I tested the code locally and it does what I want. It's a requirement to use github actions. The $ONLY... is the runvariable for the for-loop, how else would you write it? And since it works locally in parallel, why shouldn't I use it in an Action? You need to quote ';' because of how parallel reads the code

it does what I want that is not possible, as $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES = is a shell syntax for assignment. To assign a shell variable do ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES= - no spaces and no $. You need to quote ';' because of how parallel reads the code but the x odt"';' is also quoted, and it is before parallel. Additionally, YAML > makes everything a single line, which breaks your continuation lines and comments, consider |. Consider writing a script, if YAML escaping is too confusing.

The new error you show is exactly because of what KamillCuk talks about; the shell thinks you want to run = as a command. I really think > is causing mostly trouble for you, still.

@KamilCuk Fair point, seemed like I added the spaces at some point. And eventually copied the ';' there to try and fix the GitHub error. That's on me, sorry for that. I will append my new code to the question

this bash script works locally save this script to script.sh in your repo and RUN: bash ./script.sh and commit. That is much simpler than doing stuff in YAML syntax. And also allows to use shellcheck to check the scripts. the output is nowhere to be found there are delays before github runner transfers the output. Sometimes it takes seconds and multiple refreshes. Try redirecting to a file and uploading an artifact, but dunno what the output do you expect to get.

Alright, will check how to execute bash scripts in GitHub and try

So i try to run bash ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pandoc.sh $list_changed_files and I get /home/runner/work/*repo*/_repo_/pandoc.sh: No such file or directory. I also tried a few different ways to refer to the file (eg move teh script to a script folder or use conditional_pandoc.default.workdir) but it all boils down to the same error. I referenced the doc but I can't seem to find the error (the filename is copy pasted, so it shouldn't be about the spelling)

And I missed the question in your earlier comment: I expect to find a Word, PDF, TeX etc document in the directory of the markdown file with the same name & contents. Even now, an hour after the first successful run nothing shows

So after a lot of tinkering and trial-and-error here is a version which works the basic idea. Latex to pdf still throws an error because of missing packages. But instead of adding all the needed packages (listed here) I intend to get the docker image working. I will report back if this works successfully or edit this answer with a complete list of packages.
  conditional_pandoc:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-22.04'
    needs: [ condition_check_files ]
    if: needs.condition_check_files.outputs.bool_files_changed == 'true'
    env:
      list_changed_files: ${{ needs.condition_check_files.outputs.list_changed_files }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4  # In order to find the script pandoc.sh
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - uses: pandoc/actions/setup@v1
        with:
          version: 3.5
      - uses: teatimeguest/setup-texlive-action@v3  # To convert to pdf (from latex)
        with:
          packages: |
            scheme-basic
            hyperref
            xcolor
            iftex
            #TODO
      - name: Run Pandoc
        run: |
          echo "$list_changed_files"
          bash ./pandoc.sh "$list_changed_files"
      - name: Commit files # transfer the new files back into the repository
        run: |
          git config --local user.name "GH_Action_Bot"
          git add ./content
          git commit -m "GH Action: Pandoc | New output for changed files"
          git push -f origin main

The important part is that

There is a typo in my original question in the env, I edited my question
I had to add actions/checkout@v4 to find the script in the main directory pandoc.sh:

#!/bin/bash
# List types which will only use --standalone. You can easily add more extensions if you're fine with this setting
Only_Standalone_Output_Types="latex pdf html docx odt"
# Use GNU Parallel to work each file on its own cpu core.
# Pandoc creates an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree); reuse this by saving/reading from .ast
# You can easily add individual conversion rules by using pandoc after the 'done' part. Keep in mind to finish all non-comment lines with backslash
parallel --jobs 0 \
    pandoc --from markdown --to native './{}' -o './{.}.ast' ';'\
    for i in "$Only_Standalone_Output_Types"';' do \
        pandoc --from native './{.}.ast' --standalone -o './{.}.$i' ';' \
    done';' \
    rm './{.}.ast' ::: "$1"


I had to add the Commit files step in order to get the files into the repo

alternatively, here is an intermediate result: Save the whole folder to a zip-archive:



- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4  # To save the files in the repo
  with:
    name: pandoc-artifact
    path: content/

